# Program Exits Before Executing 'else' Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, sys

I am trying to make a prompt in Python 2.7. I have an infinite loop that will get the user's input using `str(raw_input('$> '))`. Then, it checks a bunch of 'if' and 'elif' statements (each one is a particular command) to see what to do with the entered command. I have also disabled KeyboardInterrupt through a 'try... except' statement, and added an 'exit' command. Here is where the problem lies. The 'exit' command runs well, printing 'Bye' and then quitting. However, so does every other unknown command.

I have tried using the built-in `quit()` and `exit()` functions and `sys.exit()`, but none of them fix the problem. I have also encased my 'if' statements in a while loop that checks if it is *not* the 'exit' command, and then used the else statement to quit. However, it just prints `Command "exit" not found.`

My question is a) why Python will execute that code for any statements after it, and b) what to do to fix this, if possible.

My theory for a) is that because Python is interpreted line by line, it reads that line and for whatever reason, executes it. However, if the command matches, it stops looking at the 'if' statement and executes the code for the entered command.

Here is a simplified version of my code, and thank you in advance.

```
from sys import exit as die

while True:
    msg = str(raw_input('$> '))
    if msg == 'test':
        print '123'
    elif msg == 'quit' or 'exit':
        print 'Bye'
        die()   
    elif msg == 'test2':
        print '456'
    else:
        print 'Command "%s" not found' % (msg)
```

If I run the 'test2' command, or an unkown command 'foo', the program will print 'Bye' and exit.

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rutsky Updated post. Is that good, or do you need anything else?

Comment: That update included the necessary detail. `if a == b or c` does not do what you are expecting it to do. Please see the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg == 'quit' or 'exit'
```

means

```
(msg == 'quit') or 'exit'
```

Comment: Oops, I completely read over that! My bad, sorry. Ugh.